# Advice on rendering schmaltz

Tags: chicken, fat, jewish-cuisine

I'd like to try rendering schmaltz, and to that end have been stripping skin off the store rotisserie chickens my family buys (I've got two chickens-worth of skin atm). In doing some research I found [a detailed article from The Splendid Table](https://www.splendidtable.org/story/how-to-make-schmaltz), but noticed that in their pictures the skin is raw to start. Is there no point to my trying to render from roasted skin? If so...any advice on what to do with all this roasted skin? I was thinking maybe a [variation on bacon salt](https://www.platingsandpairings.com/homemade-bacon-salt/)....

Also, whether I get to rendering schmaltz now or later, any general advice? I've had bad experiences with rendering fats in the past, but I'm pretty sure it was due to my lack of patience. As far as I can tell, it's very low heat and a lot of time that renders fat properly.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Most of the fat has already been rendered out of roasted chicken skin. I wouldn't bother trying to render more. Crisp it in the oven, crumble it roughly, and sprinkle it over things, if you're looking for something to do with it.

As for rendering schmalz, it's not difficult. Go slow and start with a bit of other fat if you're not using a non-stick pan.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the best results rendering all sort of fat (pork, duck, chicken...) with the following process.

1. Begin with raw, cold, skin and fat.
2. Cut or chop it up as finely as you have patience for.
3. Place in pot with a small amount of water, just to cover the bottom of pan and avoid sticking.
4. Place over lowest possible heat.  Avoid boiling and sizzling.  Low and very slow.  It will likely take hours.
5. Strain